# Odoo return action or warning

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I am using Odoo10 and have the membership module and attendance module installed. I want to scan in the barcode but have it check the membership state before allowing it to proceed. The default code checks to see if there is a valid barcode so I am trying to copy that.

This odoo default code for checking barcode

```
@api.model
    def attendance_scan(self, barcode):
        """ Receive a barcode scanned from the Kiosk Mode and change the attendances of corresponding partner.
            Returns either an action or a warning.
        """
        partner = self.search([('barcode', '=', barcode)], limit=1)
        return partner and partner.attendance_action('base_attendance.hr_attendance_action_kiosk_mode') or \
            {'warning': _('No partner corresponding to barcode %(barcode)s') % {'barcode': barcode}}
```

I want membership_state = paid so I tried

```
@api.model
    def attendance_scan(self, barcode):
        """ Receive a barcode scanned from the Kiosk Mode and change the attendances of corresponding partner.
            Returns either an action or a warning.
        """
        partner = self.search([('barcode', '=', barcode)], limit=1) and self.partner.membership_state = (self.paid)
        return partner and partner.attendance_action('base_attendance.hr_attendance_action_kiosk_mode') or \
            {'warning': _('No partner corresponding to barcode %(barcode)s') % {'barcode': barcode}}
```

The error i get is

```
partner = self.search([('barcode', '=', barcode)], limit=1) and self.partner.membership_state = (self.paid)
AttributeError: 'res.partner' object has no attribute 'partner'
```

membership_state has multiple states like none,canceled,waiting,invoiced and paid. I just do no
t know how to call the state

Answer (score 0):

I think your `self` is itself a recordset of the partner. If yes, then you don't need to access `partner` from `self` (self.partner.membership_state).

Try this: `self.membership_state`

If `self` is a different object, then please post the class definition as well.

Comment: I tried `partner = self.search([('barcode', '=', barcode)], limit=1) and self.membership_state == ('self.paid')` but the barcode wont scan. I get no errors but it just wont scan. `self.membership_state = (self.paid)` I get odoo error and it wont run

Comment: Your condition evaluates like this: find partner that has your barcode - if none found, `partner` becomes an empty recordset otherwise `partner` becomes boolean as a result of the next condition. I think you should have searched for partner like `partner = self.search([('barcode', '=', barcode), ('membership_state', '=', 'paid')])`